# Wpf ToggleButton change border background when togglebutton is pressed

Tags: wpf, xaml, toggle

I have a `ToggleButton` and when I press it needs to change a border color. Here is my code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="30" Height="15">
                        <Image Source="/Res/combobox_icon.PNG"/>
                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Border Name="br" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Red" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="56" Margin="60,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="125"/>
    <ToggleButton Margin="291,72,94,153">

    </ToggleButton>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Well, what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like that. You also can change the BorderBrush in the same way.

```
<Grid>
    <Border Name="br">
        <Border.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tog, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <DataTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                        </DataTrigger.Setters>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
    </Border>
    <ToggleButton Name="tog" Margin="20,20,20,20" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: thank u very much but can that toggle be in a style and not the mian xmal?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand. Do you mean a style for the Border or the ToggleButton.

Comment: i mean the toggle is actually inside a combobox style what i need is when i press that toggle in the combobox it drops down the list but i also need it to change the border color i tried ur code it works but with toggles that are in the main xaml code not inside a style

Comment: In a style you don't have named Controls so you can't work with 'ElementName' in the Binding. Maybe you can work with 'RelativeSource' but that is more complicated and depends on the special case.